# H.M or G.M in Bisection method

Tags: numerical-methods

In bisection method we use A.M mean to bisect the interval and to find the approximate root for the equation $f(x)=0$ can we use the H.M or G.M instead of A.M?
If yes what are the consequences?

Comment: The first obvious consequence is it won't be the bisection method any more. But it will still converge, provided that your values of $x$ are all positive.

Comment: Or use the Fibonacci sequence to split 1:1, 1:2,2:3, 3:5, 5:8 etc. How do you split by G.M. if $a<0<b$?